# MongoDB - Push element if not exists or change position if exists

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to prepare a query that updates an array.
I'd like to:

- Add a new item to the top of the array
- If exists - do not add the same - just move to the top

How the query should look like?

I'm thinking to use this one, but I think this query doesn't change position if element exists:

```
db.actions.update(
   { _id: xxx },
   { $addToSet: { ofers: { $each: [ "one", "two", "three" ] } } }
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the same with two queries.
First **PULL** and then **PUSH**

```
db.actions.update(
   { _id: xxx },
   { $pull: { ofers: {$in : [ "one", "two", "three" ] }} }
 );

db.actions.update(
   { _id: xxx },
   { $push: { ofers: { $each: [ "one", "two", "three" ], $position: 0 }} }
 );
```